# Yii2 Assets - Sub-Resource Integrity

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm working through all my Yii2 asset bundles to incorporate Sub-Resource Integrity. So right now I have...

```
namespace some\amazing\space;

class AmazingAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = 'path/to/asset/files'; // or
    public $baseUrl = '//url/to/asset/files';
    public $js = [
        'js/amazingscript.min.js',
    ];
    public $jsOptions = [
        'integrity' => 'hash-of-js/amazingscript.min.js';
        'crossorigin' => 'anonymous',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'some\useful\ThingAsset',
    ];
}
```

Now I want to add some more amazing sauce to my bundle & get...

```
namespace some\amazing\space;

class MoreAmazingAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = 'path/to/asset/files'; // or
    public $baseUrl = '//url/to/asset/files';
    public $js = [
        'js/amazingscript.min.js',
        'js/moreamazingscript.min.js',
    ];
    public $jsOptions = [
        'integrity' => 'hash-of-js/amazingscript.min.js';
        'crossorigin' => 'anonymous',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'some\useful\ThingAsset',
    ];
}
```

But here I'm stuck because the `jsOptions` will be applied to both .js files. The only way I can see is to break it into 2 bundles, with one requiring the other...

```
namespace some\amazing\space;

class MoreAmazingAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = 'path/to/asset/files'; // or
    public $baseUrl = '//url/to/asset/files';
    public $js = [
        'js/moreamazingscript.min.js',
    ];
    public $jsOptions = [
        'integrity' => 'hash-of-js/moreamazingscript.min.js';
        'crossorigin' => 'anonymous',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'some\amazing\space\AmazingAsset',
    ];
}
```

& then...

```
namespace some\amazing\space;

class AmazingAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = 'path/to/asset/files'; // or
    public $baseUrl = '//url/to/asset/files';
    public $js = [
        'js/amazingscript.min.js',
    ];
    public $jsOptions = [
        'integrity' => 'hash-of-js/amazingscript.min.js';
        'crossorigin' => 'anonymous',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'some\useful\ThingAsset',
    ];
}
```

Any alternatives?

Comment: umm cant get what you actually want. do you want the `$jsOptions` to be applicable to only one specific file that you are specifying in the`$js` ?

Comment: also if you could add the actual names it would be more readable and easy to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Salam Muhammad, the `$jsOptions` for the two (or more) js files differs in that the value of `'integrity'` which should be a hash of the specific js file. I think the generalised form is as clear as using specific files with the benefit of showing that it is a problem broader than my case.

Comment: Wassalam, so you want to be able to specify different `hash` for the 2 js files inside the `Asset`?

Comment: added an answer below see if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what i understand you want to be able to specify the hash for the `integrity` attribute for the 2 `js` files separately and currently by using `$jsOptions` the same hash is supplied for all the script files.

If the above is correct you can specify the attribute from within the `$js` by specifying the sources as an array like below. rather than creating 2 separate `AssetBundles` for both of them.

```
public $js = [
        ['js/some.js','integrity'=>'SOME_SHA_HASH' ],
        ['js/another.js','integrity'=>'ANOTHER_SHA_HASH' ],
    ];
```

just remember that

> "The hash algorithm must be one of `sha256`, `sha384`, or `sha512`,
>   followed by a '-' character."

your Code will look like below

```
namespace some\amazing\space;

class CombinedAmazingAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = 'path/to/asset/files'; // or
    public $baseUrl = '//url/to/asset/files';
    public $js = [
        ['js/amazingscript.min.js','integrity' => 'hash-of-js/amazingscript.min.js'],
        ['js/moreamazingscript.min.js','integrity' => 'hash-of-js/moreamazingscript.min.js'],
    ];
    public $jsOptions = [
        'crossorigin' => 'anonymous',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'some\useful\ThingAsset',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Salam Muhammad, that looks exactly what I was after, & much more elegant than splitting it into two assets. As I've been considering this, I've also come to wondering whether `crossorigin` should be used for resources on the same host as the site. Seems redundant to me because that situation isn't cross origin. However I think that's another question. Thank you.

Comment: Wassalam @Pedro, Glad it worked, normal script elements pass minimal information to the window.onerror for scripts which do not pass the standard CORS checks. To allow error logging for sites which use a separate domain for static media, use this attribute. See [**`CORS settings attributes`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) for a more descriptive explanation of its valid arguments. as per your description it looks redundant.